# What are the differences between personality and character?

Tags: differences

The LDOCE defines *character* and *personality* as follows:

- Character: the particular combination of qualities that makes someone a particular type of person
- Personality: someone’s *character*, especially the way they behave towards other people

My only takeaway from these is that *personality* may be an aspect of *character* but not vice versa.

So what are the differences between *character* and *personality*? Which categories do traits like *generosity, kindness, rashness, sensibility, humorousness, persuasiveness, charisma* belong to. Illustrative examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You've never known someone who was friendly and outgoing and who always seemed agreeable, but who would rob you blind given the opportunity?

Comment: (Note that there's another definition of "character".)

Answer (score 2):

the word *character* is used when talking about whether someone is good or bad, or honest or dishonest and the word *personality* when talking about a person's particular behavior in social situations, e.g. friendly or unfriendly

Answer (score 0):

A [simple search](http://www.google.com/search?q=character+vs+personality) will give many references, but briefly and generally:

**Personality** refers to surface, social qualities like friendliness, humor, and agreeability.

**Character** refers to the underlying moral qualities of one's nature, including honesty and dependability.